# Parsing google sheet with colors

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api-python-client

Is there any ways to read colors from cells in google sheet without using google API?
API has limits and my sheet is around 200x400 size, it'll take years to parse...

To read and parse values i used `/export` in url which exports into xlsx format by default. But this way doesn't keep cell colors by unknown reasons.

`/export?format=ods`  works fine, has all necesary colors but I can't find any info about getting cell colors from ods sheet in python...

Google query, like: `/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html` doesn't give any colors.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use google API directly.

Starting from [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet) there's a way to request specific values by going down a tree of properties

```
# as always create service instance
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=CREDS)

# now request any required properties according to API
fields_cells = "sheets(data(rowData(values(userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat/backgroundColor))))"
request = service.spreadsheets().get(
    spreadsheetId=sheet_id,
    ranges=range_name,
    fields=fields_cells,
)
resp = request.execute()
```

it will return requested values on specified range with only one request